# Restoring Linux System Files from Deja Dup Backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup, restore

So I inadvertently deleted or moved a system file or directory as super user on my Lenovo Yoga Pro with Ubuntu.  I do have a backup created with Deja Dup.  And I can get to the command prompt but not to the normal Ubuntu desktop.  I've seen examples where restoring is easy from the desktop when the applications are running.  But my system is damaged now so neither the desktop or applications run, just the command line by booting into it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

deja-dup does cli, sure:

```
deja-dup --restore file
```

That should help if you've done a complete backup.